# Machine Learning - SVM - How to calculate bias when calculate vector W?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, gradient-descent

I am writing code of SVM Primal that uses SGD (Stochastic SubGradient Descent) for optimize the vector W.

The classification methos is sign(w*x + bias).
My question is how to find the best bias for it?
I guess that it has to do during the W optimizing, but how? I have no idea.

Comment: What language are you programming this in?

Comment: Python, but it's not relevant, I am not going to use scikit-learn, I want to do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis is `sign(<w, x> + b)`, think for a second about `x' = [x 1]`, then you could express your hypothesis as `sign(<w', x'>)`, where `w' = [w b]`. I hope it clearly shows that `b` is not any different from `w`'s (the only difference is that your regularizing term `||w||^2` does not involve `b`). Thus you just need `d L/ d b` where `L` is your loss function.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why `x' = [x 1]` if `w' = [w b]`, can you explain it?

Comment: <w, x> + b = <w, x> + <[b], [1]> = <[w b], [x 1]> = <w', x'> (by writing [x 1] I mean "x with concatenated 1 as a new dimension")

Comment: Thank you very much! (the last sentece I understood myself...)